# Swift Xcode workspace, project unable to find a separate source code file (in Compile Sources)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1.

The repo can be found at https://github.com/ippoippo/thornbird
You will need to create your own `SpikeKeysForTesting`.swift file, using the `SpikeKeysForTesting`.swift_example as a template.

Anyway, the main problem I am having is that I have source file located in a directory which I was intending to use as a common source directory.
It's a similar technique used by Moya (https://github.com/AshFurrow/Moya) and also documented here : http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/2014/6/30/creating-a-pure-swift-framework-for-both-ios-and-mac

However, when I try to build my ThornbirdFramework project inside the Workspace, the ThornbirdFrameworkTests class is unable to resolve the Thornbird class (as defined in ./thornbird/Thornbird.swift).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilt everything, seems OK now.